# How to permit creator to destroy his own record with Devise on Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When the user is logged in, only the user who create the record can destroy his own record.
What should I add to the code below??

```
  def destroy

    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "topic deleted!"

  end
```

Comment: Can you post the parameters that are sent to the controller?

Comment: Thanks,Tigraine is almost getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not really devise but a authorization solution like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Devise can only authenticate users and verify that they are logged in and active. What you need is a way to determine if the user has the right to delete this topic or not.

You can of course roll your own like this:

```
  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    if @topic.user_id == current_user.id
      @topic.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "topic deleted!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "not allowed"
    end
  end
```

(The code assumes you have a `belongs_to :creator, :class_name => :user` association set up in your Topic.. But you get the idea).

But using something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) will make your life a whole lot easier and would reduce the code to something like this:

```
  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :destroy, @topic
    @topic.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "topic deleted!"
  end
```

With your ability file (See [defining abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities)) set up like this:

```
can :manage, Topic, :owner_id => user.id
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's almost there!! Is '@topic.creator' valid??? am I usually supposed to write like @topic.user_id instead???

Comment: I'm using 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'. I replaced comments with topics here. but if there is any easy trick to compare comments's creator and devise's current user. please tell me how.

Comment: Sure. I guess you can compare comment.user_id to current_user.id. I'll look at the docs tomorrow.

Comment: I updated the answer.. According to the migrations from your library (https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration/templates/migration.rb) it seems like the user_id property is what you are looking for